# map proxy-iterator conflicts C++20 iterator concepts

Tags: c++, iterator, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm trying to write a wrapper class that interprets a `std::vector<T>` as a mapping of integers to `T`s. As I want it to behave like a `map`, its iterators should dereference to `(key, value)` pairs. Since there are no such pairs in memory, the `reference` type of my corresponding iterator class is a bit unconventional:

```cpp
  using value_type = std::pair<Key, Value>;
  using reference = std::pair<Key, Value&>;
```

For the corresponding `const_iterator`, this becomes

```cpp
  using value_type = std::pair<Key, const Value>;
  using reference = std::pair<Key, const Value&>;
```

Now, however, my `const_iterator` no longer satisfies `std::indirectly_readable` (and, thus, `std::forward_iterator` and, thus, `std::random_access_iterator`) because

```
no type named 'type' in 'struct std::common_reference<std::pair<long unsigned int, const int&>&&, std::pair<long unsigned int, const int>&>'
```

(see https://godbolt.org/z/s89z56rY7) or the full code here:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

template<class Value, class VType, class RType>
struct _vector_map_iterator {
    Value* _data = nullptr;
    size_t index = 0;
    using value_type = VType;
    using reference = RType;
    using difference_type = ptrdiff_t;
    using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
    
    reference operator*() const { return {index, *_data}; }
    _vector_map_iterator& operator++() { ++index; return *this; }
    _vector_map_iterator operator++(int) {_vector_map_iterator res = *this; ++(*this); return res; }
    bool operator==(const _vector_map_iterator& other) const { return _data == other.data; }
};
template<class T>
using vmap_iterator = _vector_map_iterator<T, pair<size_t, T>, pair<size_t, T&>>;
template<class T>
using vmap_const_iterator = _vector_map_iterator<const T, pair<size_t, const T>, pair<size_t, const T&>>;

using I = vmap_const_iterator<int>;
//static_assert(std::common_reference_with<typename I::reference&&, typename I::value_type&>);
static_assert(forward_iterator<I>);

template<class Value>
struct vector_map {
    vector<Value> _raw_data;
    using iterator = vmap_iterator<Value>;
    using const_iterator = vmap_const_iterator<Value>;
    iterator begin() { return {_raw_data.data(), 0}; }
    const_iterator begin() const { return {_raw_data.data(), 0}; }
    vector_map(const initializer_list<Value>& lst): _raw_data(lst) {};
};

int main(){
    const vector_map<int> int_map = {1,2,3};
    const auto it =  int_map.begin();
    cout << (*it).first << ": " << (*it).second << '\n';
}
```

My question would be: is there a sensible (I specifically do not want to store key-value-pairs in the vector!) design for such an iterator class that also adheres to `std::random_access_iterator`?

EDIT: more details + full example

Comment: It is not immediately clear what is the problem. When you say 'breaks' do you mean conceptual break or is it a compilation error?

Comment: "*this now breaks the std::forward_iterator (and, thus, std::random_access_iterator) concept because that one expects value_type and reference to "share a common reference type" or something like that*" Um, no it doesn't. Not the [actual concept you cited](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/forward_iterator). Please provide an [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, along with the error in question.

Comment: [This is likely going to be fixed in C++23](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2214r0.html#a-tuple-that-is-readable). Until then...you pretty much need your own `pair`.

Comment: As I see it you implementation would also be inconsisten with the legacy definition of [`ForwardIterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator): _"     The type std::iterator_traits<It>::reference must be exactly [1)] T& if It satisfies LegacyOutputIterator (It is mutable) [or 2)]  const T& otherwise (It is constant),     (where T is the type denoted by std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type)"_